# How to find a number with link

Tags: vba, ms-word

As below picture, I "crtl+H" want to find "Table 2", but can't find this word because "2" with a link.

[image]

II try use vba code

```
selection.find.clearformatting 
with selection.find .text="Table 2" 
   .wrap = wdfindcontinue 
   .forward = true 
   .font.bold = true
   .replacement.text = "ss"
   .execute replace:=wdreplaceAll
   end with
```

but can't find this "table 2".

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question if possible to include some space between the question text and the image text. Is the image shown an object within MS Word? And what does this mean "can't find this word because "2" with a link" ?

Comment: @ QHarr thanks, at begin I only want to find "Table 2" to check format if it is correct, but I use with "ctrl + H" to find,  I find it skip the "Table 2" in picture. I try to find what is this "table 2" different with other normal, So i guess maybe because "2" with a link.

Comment: If it is an image within Word i don't think you can't search in this way for the text "Table 2." The image itelf would have some kind of object reference. If it is in fact, an image within Word, i can only think of image recognition algorithms which is way beyond a simple find.

Comment: What is selected when you run this code, and is that your actual VBA? It doesn't seem like it was copied from the VB editor.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in the other people, this number is "Field", May be because the field braces are not generally entered from the keyboard curly braces, just to indicate the start and end of a domain-wide flag, so the search function does not can find this.